# No matching overloads found for *static* com.aspose.cells

Tags: python, java, aspose, aspose-cells, jpype

I have this code in python running jpype and asposeCells libraries, the purpose of this code is to convert numbers in text format (cells with green arrow) into actual numeric value

```
import jpype
import asposecells
jpype.statJVM()
from asposecells.api import Workbook, Cells

workbook = Workbook(Filepath)
workbook.getWorksheets().get(0)
Cells.convertStringToNumericValue()
workbook.save(Filepath)

jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

And I encountered this error:

No matching overloads found for *static* com.aspose.cells.Cells.convertStringToNumericValue(), options are public void com.aspose.cells.Cells.convertStringToNumericValue()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
TypeError: No matching overloads found for *static* com.aspose.cells.Cells.convertStringToNumericValue(), options are public void com.aspose.cells.Cells.convertStringToNumericValue()

Appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue, thanks!

The code is use to convert numbers that are in text format into actual number values, server environment is in Linux so I can't use win32 module, so aspose is my only known option to use, but I'm not expert in converting codes from Java to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Please note, Cells class is not static, the method convertStringToNumericValue is not static method. Please try the following sample code:

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```java
import jpype
import asposecells
jpype.startJVM()
from asposecells.api import Workbook, Cells

workbook = Workbook()
cells = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells()
cells.convertStringToNumericValue()

jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

Moreover, we recommend you to kindly try latest version/fix (Aspose.Cells for Python via Java v22.12) of the API.

Should you have further queries, you may also post your queries in other [forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.